# Turn a instance to its class's child type (calling super for classmethod)

Tags: python, oop

```
class Parent:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, name):
        return cls(name)

    def greeting(self):
        print 'Hello ' + self.name


class Child(Parent):

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, name):
        p = Parent.get(name)
        p.full_name = 'James ' + name
        return p

    def greeting(self):
        print 'Bye ' + self.full_name
```

as you can see, I added an attribute `full_name` in the `Child`'s `get` method to the instance of Parent, the problem is, now the instance if still in the type of `Parent`, how could I turn it into `Child`?

Comment: @thefourtheye then it will call itself..

Comment: Your sentence with lots of commas is making my head spin.   Can you clarify the question?   I'm not clear on what is the relationship between "I added full_name to the Child's get" and "how can I turn a Parent into a Child"

Comment: @wong2 Sorry. I meant `p = cls(name)`

Comment: @thefourtheye yeah, but this is the simplified code. it's hard to call `p = cls(name)` in the actual situation.

Answer (score 1):

Make object as Parent base class:

```
class Parent(object):
```

and then change this line in Child `p = Parent.get(name)` to:

```
p = super(Child, cls).get(name)
```

This way `super(Child, cls).get(name)` will bound cls (Child) to parent `get` method, so in result `Parent.get` will be called with `Child` class as `cls` parameter. Of course to make this work you need new style classes that why `object` should be in `Parent` bases!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change the type of the returned object. What you need to do is call the parent class's implementation of the method with the same `cls` the child class's method is using. This is one of the things [`super`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) is for. First, you'll need to make sure you're using new-style classes:

```
class Parent(object):
    # continue as usual
```

Python has two implementations of the class system, because they didn't get it right the first time. Always inherit from `object` if you're not inheriting from anything else, to make sure you're using the newer, better system.

Now, `super`. Instead of using `Parent.get(name)`, use a `super` call:

```
p = super(Child, cls).get(name)
```

`p` will have the correct type, since `cls` in the parent's method was the same class as `cls` in the child's method. (Note that if you later added a `Grandchild` class, this line would produce `Grandchild` objects instead of `Child` objects. This is most likely the right behavior.)